# Dealing with css @print in wp-admin

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to print just one div inside wordpress admin with 'window.print()'. I could enqueue the css to just load in the page that I want and to hide all the elements but the div I want to print. The problem is that the text formating and the image background aren't in the print preview.
The css:

```
#brgprint .toplogo{
        background-image: url(https://www.agilsaude.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo_agilsaude3.png);
        width:100px;
        height:60px;
        margin:auto;
    }
    #brgprint p.assinatura{
        width:200px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border-top: 1px black;
    }
@media print {
    #adminmenuback, #adminmenuwrap, #wpfooter, #wpbody-content .update-nag, #contextual-help-link-wrap, #wpbody-content .wrap h2, #woo_vou_check_voucher_code_container .handlediv, #woo_vou_check_voucher_code_container h3, .woo-vou-check-code tbody tr, .woo-vou-voucher-code-submit-wrap .button-primary {display:none}
    #brgprint {width:100%!important;margin:0!important;
    display:block!important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    }
    #brgprint .toplogo{
        display:block!important;
        background-image: url(https://www.agilsaude.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo_agilsaude3.png)!important;
        width:100px!important;
        height:60px!important;
        margin:auto!important;
    }
    #brgprint p.assinatura{
        width:200px!important;
        margin: 20px auto!important;
        border-top: 1px black!important;
    }
    #wpwrap, #wpcontent, #wpbody, #wpbody-content, #woo_vou_check_voucher_code_wrap.post-box-container,     #woo_vou_check_voucher_code_container.postbox, #woo_vou_check_voucher_code_container.postbox.inside, tr.woo-vou-voucher-code-submit-wrap, tr.woo-vou-voucher-code-submit-wrap td {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

The div I want to print:

```
<div class="brgprint">
  <div class="toplogo" style="background-image: url(https://www.agilsaude.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo_agilsaude3.png);width:100px;height:60px;margin:auto;display:block;float:none;"></div>
  <h2 style:"text-align:center"="">Declaração de atendimento</h2>
  <p>Declaro que o cliente Helder Lima, portador do CPF , na presente data está realizando o atendimento do produto e/ou serviço Teste de Voucher na clínica e/ou profissional Agil Saude.</p><p> Receberei o valor de R$ 100 pela prestação de serviços.</p><p>14 / 08 / 2014</p>
  <p style="width:200px;margin: 20px auto;border-top: 1px;">Assinatura</p></div>
```

It is displaying correctly in the browser, but it's printing just plain-text and the top-logo isn't displaying.

Comment: Please, check out my answer and approve it if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `img` instead of inline styling the logo. Then style it in your CSS file using the class.

```
<img class="toplogo" src="https://www.agilsaude.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo_agilsaude3.png">
```

**DEMO** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5k4mxa2/)

**EDIT** And `brgprint` is not an ID, it's a class, in your CSS you keep refering to it like `#brgprint` while you should be doing `.brgprint`, have a look at this JSFiddle and you will see that I changed it into an ID in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/r5k4mxa2/1/

Comment: I changed it to a class and then back to id... it was outdated. Your answer worked very well... thanks!